Can a ideal voltometer even measure potential
Ideal voltmeter has infinite resistance that would imply no current passes through it , hence by ohms law potential through it will be 0 . Here the voltmeter is made by adding shunt resistance in series and whole arrangement is in parallel to the points across which potential is measured

There are no ideal voltmeters. There are electrometers, however.

Your reasoning is wrong. An infinite resistance implies a null current, not a null voltage drop, as $I = V/R$. It is the potential drop that causes the current, and not the other way round.
A mathematically handwavy/circular reasoning would be that if $I\to 0$ and $R\to\infty$, then $IR$ can be finite, as this would be a $0\cdot\infty$ limit. An example would be using the parametrization $R=x$, so you must have $I = V/x$. Then in the limit, you would still have $IR = V$, even if you take the limit $R\to\infty$.
In any case, in reality we can forget about perfect voltimeters, and only use ones with very high resistance, which in turn only allow for very small currents.

Electrometers and electroscopes are devices which measure potential difference and charge, but do have a finite resistance which is very large.
Voltmeters with an infinite resistance do not exist.
A gold leaf electroscope can be calibrated to measure potential difference.
It is a voltmeter with a very high resistance because air and the material (usually classed as an insulator) between the leaves and the case have a very high resistivity.
The best electrometers have leakage current of order femtoamperes, but they do have a finite resistance.
The Wikipedia article electrometers gives more details.
